# after upgrading manjaro at 11th Feb, nemo can not start

Tags: desktop, manjaro

I was using **Manjaro 18.0.2 Illyria** all fine until yesterday, I updated it with a bunch of software.

After this update (reboot), I noticed that I lost icons on desktop, and right click not working. I run

> nemo --version

in terminal, it said:

> error while loading shared libraries: **libexempi.so.3**: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I checked this post:
https://forum.manjaro.org/t/testing-update-2019-01-27-kernels-browsers-certbot-deepin-wine/73506/28
and I understand that exempi of **2.5.0-1** has no so.3 now, but nemo still wants it.

The question is, under this circumstance, how to fix it and use nemo, please?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, after another packages update, nemo back to normal.